# Creating a Group for a Subsite creates that group for the Parent Site as well

Tags: development, farm-solution

What I'm doing (abstract):

A SharePoint List has an EventReceiever at which I'm accessing "ItemAdded" to create a new SPWeb for that new List Item.

That subsite needs it's own set of permission (Imagine Manager, Debuty, etc.). When I'm adding a Group to that SPWeb's SiteGroups and adding a RoleAssignment for the new SPWeb the Group also gets added in the Parent Site, which I do not want.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I dont think that you can change this behaviour because in order to access the resources of the subsite, an identity would have to first access the resources of the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. SharePoint groups are available across the entire site collection, even if they are only used in a subsite of that site collection.